# Send data in CodeIgniter use store procedure

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, codeigniter-3

I will send 2 data, one is a "kode" and two is a name of "dataupadate" table. Here I use store procedure to execute command. When I it, run error appears

> Warning: include(D:\xampp\htdocs\ittools\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\ittools\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269

---

> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'D:\xampp\htdocs\ittools\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\ittools\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269"

My code is

controller

```
function send() {
  $kode = $this - > input - > post('inv');
  $dataupdate = $this - > input - > post('dataupdate');
  $this - > ssu_model - > dosend($kode, $dataupdate);
  redirect('ssu');
}
```

Model

```
function dosend($kode, $dataupdate) {
  $query = $this->db->query("EXEC wl_update_inv_tagih_sub_ssu '".$kode."','".$dataupdate."' ");
  return $query->result();
}
```

view

```
<form id="form_inv" action="<?php echo site_url('persediaan/ssu/send');?>" method="post">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" name="nameinv" class="form-control" id="nameinv" placeholder="INV" />
    <input type="hidden" name="inv" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" />
    <input type="hidden" name="dataupdate" class="form-control" value="INV" disabled/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-flat btn-warning" id="btnLoad" >Update</button>                      
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

help me..what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what code is triggering the PHP error but when it is triggered it cannot find the needed view file.

Here are a couple things to check.

First, make sure the file `error_php.php` is in the directory `C:\xampp\htdocs\ittools\application\views\errors\html`.

Second, in `config.php` check the value assigned to `$config['error_views_path']`. If you have the standard file structure it should be

```
$config['error_views_path'] = '';
```

You also should try changing the line

```
$query = $this->db->query("EXEC wl_update_inv_tagih_sub_ssu '".$kode."','".$dataupdate."' ");
```

to this

```
$query = $this->db->query("EXEC wl_update_inv_tagih_sub_ssu $kode, $dataupdate");
```

And see if you get a different outcome.